# Writing a parameterized test method in spock

Tags: testing, groovy, spock

I'm writing a test in Spock and currently, this is the base structure:

```
def "someTest"(String str, Class<? extends SomeClass> clazz) {

    setup:
       (current implementation)
       obj.get("Sample1")
       obj.get("Sample2")
       obj.get("Sample3")
       ... so on

       (what I want to implement)
       object.get(str)

    when:
    ...

    then:
    ...
}
```

I need to use `str` and `clazz` in `setup:`, `when:` and `then:` and so I need a way to call the method multiple times.

I've already read some tuts online: https://www.testwithspring.com/lesson/writing-parameterized-tests-with-spock-framework/ but really have no idea on how to implement it with non-primitive types

Comment: Call what method multiple times? The test?

Comment: @doelleri Yes, I need to call it multiple times (if its possible in spock). I can certainly do the test by copy-pasting everything for each str and clazz but it'll be too long

Comment: @HeanzyZabala do you need to perform obj.get(str) so many times in one test scenario or you have multiple test scenarios?

Comment: it would help if the 'current implementation' actually compiled.

Answer (score 0):

In spock you provide the values for parametrized tests in the `where:` part, as an Ascii 'table' or List.
Spock uses AST transforms to convert such a table into separate method invocations. So it looks like magic.

```
  @Unroll // formats method name. Can be on class level
  def "Name of #clazz is not #str"(String str, Class clazz) {
    setup:
    // TODO: real setup
    str == clazz.name

    // TODO: when/ then only useful for stimulus-response tests
    when:
    str == clazz.name

    then:
    str == clazz.name

    // TODO: expect not needed when using when/then
    expect:
    str == clazz.name

    where:
    str                  | clazz
    "java.lang.String"   | String.class
    "java.lang.Integer"  | Integer.class

  }
```

This may not look like it, but the method is run multiple times for each line in the 'table' of values, which you can check by using invalid values and making each method invocation fail.

Comment: don't forget the `@Unroll` annotation ;-)

Comment: Why do you have `str == clazz.name` in every block, even those it makes no sense? for this example a simple `expect` would be the appropriate block.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings OP asked "I need to use str and clazz in setup, when and then", I merely tried to show it's possible in all. I was lazy to make a better example, feel free to edit example boldly (I wont mind). I added comments to clarify a bit.